# How to convert for loop into forEach(in my case) using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am learning some new concept in javascript, but i am stuck at a point, i am using a for loop to get details of each element of array one by one but one of my friends suggested me to use forEach instead , but now i really don't know how to do that , i went through many sites like w3schools ,some stackoverflow answers but i unable to get it as i am new to this language, so here is my code

```
var problemList =["9000" , "9001" , "9002"];
for(var count =0 ; count<problemList.length ; count++)
{
 getProblemDetails(problemList[count]) // this is function in which i am passing each element of my array to fetch the details of that element
}
```

Now my request is how can i do the same thing using forEach loop?

Comment: Do you know how to use a `forEach` loop? If not, the best place to start is by [looking it up](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Comment: can you please share what you tried and how it failed?

Comment: For what it's worth there's no noteable reason to use a forEach over a for loop here, I'd be interested to know why this recommendation was made.

Comment: @Jack hardcastle what i got to know from him is it increases the readiness and performance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read more about [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```js
var problemList = ["9000", "9001", "9002"];

problemList.forEach(problem => {
    getProblemDetails(problem);
});
```

Comment: Thanks this worked for me

Answer (score -2):

yo can use for ... of statement.

Something like this:

```
for (let item of problemList) { 
      getProblemDetails(item);
}
```

I hope this is useful to you!

Comment: Thanks this worked for me